# Why don't terminals support standard keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: command-line

On OS X you can use `cmd+left/right` to jump to the beginning/end of the line, or `option+left/right` to jump word by word. In just about every application.

But not in the Terminal. Nor iTerm. You have to learn other, weird ways of jumping around... `ctrl+a` jumps you to the beginning of the line. `ctrl+e` is end of line. For jumping word-by-word it's `ctrl+b` or `ctrl+f`. The letters seem completely arbitrary.

On Windows it's even worse – you can't even `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`. The official method for copying and pasting is [insane](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx).

Why is this?

---

NB. I'm not asking for help with configuring my terminal. I just want to understand why this situation exists.

Comment: The OS X terminal conforms to the [`readline` standard](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts) used in just about all POSIX shells, which is based on Emacs line editing commands. Windows is just being Windows in that it marches to its own beat and doesn't think a console is worth having proper keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Have you tried [searching](http://superuser.com/search?q=terminal+shortcuts) over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a conceptual programming problem within the scope defined in the [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: On MacOSX, Linux and other POSIX-like systems, you could use some other shell, e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [fish](http://fishshell.com/) and customize their behavior to suite your needs. You could even code your own shell if you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

`cmd+left/right` in OS X and `ctrl+c` in Windows are no less arbitrary than terminal shortcuts.

To answer your question, it's because of how these things developed. At some point when the Bourne shell was designed, back in the 1970s, someone decided which keyboard shortcuts should do what. Your modern OS X terminal is running bash, which descends from Bourne, and for compatibility is has many of the same features. OS X is Unix at its core, with a GUI and other features built on top by Apple. I suppose a better question would be "Why doesn't the OS X GUI use the same keyboard shortcuts as the terminal?" The reason is probably that, being a different user interface, there are approaches that work better than others.

It's the same deal with Windows. Windows was originally just a GUI sitting on top of DOS. While that's no longer the case, cmd (the Windows shell) still uses many of the same conventions as the DOS shell for compatibility reasons.

Comment: "cmd+left/right in OS X and ctrl+c in Windows are no less arbitrary than terminal shortcuts." Really? Arrow keys move your cursor left and right, so it makes sense for modifier+arrow to move it by a longer distance. And ctrl+c/v is has logic behind it; the `c/v` keys are adjacent and very easy to type with a modifier key (easier than `ctrl+y` for example), which is good because copy/paste are by far the most commonly used keyboard shortcuts. These are deliberate design decisions. They are not arbitrary.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I wasn't saying that the OS X and Windows shortcuts were arbitrary; I was saying that if you call the terminal shortcuts arbitrary, you might as well call the others that too. I don't know the design history of Unix and DOS, but I'm sure those were deliberate design decisions as well. The only reason you consider the GUI keyboard shortcuts "standard" is that you're used to them. In this realm, "standards" are more or less _de facto_.

Comment: OK, so there was probably some logic to the shortcut letters chosen in the 70s. But now computers have changed, and OS X has system-wide keyboard shortcuts that are much easier to remember. So the question remains, why haven't terminals been updated to support these new system-wide shortcuts (in addition to supporting the old 70s shortcuts)? Other apps modernize, why not terminals? I'm guessing there's some logistical reason, but I still don't know what it is.

Comment: Well, one of the biggest reasons is that they conflict. `Ctrl+C` means copy on Windows; it means abort task in pretty much every shell ever. Obviously not something you want to mix up. But there's also the fact that it's ingrained—why and how can you change something that's been in place for the last 40 years? Furthermore, in both examples on Windows and OS X, the majority of users don't ever touch the command line, giving little incentive to change it to parallel the rest of the system.

Comment: Perhaps it should be pointed out that in most, if not all, terminals running some variant of a *nix shell, the keyboard shortcuts are totally user-configurable.  For instance, I have F8 bound to a command to edit the Makefile in the current directory, with "bindkey -c "\e[19~" 'x Makefile'"

Comment: @callum: And here's a fun fact: In all Mac OS X applications that use standard widgets, most of the 'arbitrary' shortcuts from the terminal work just fine. Go ahead, try ctrl-a in TextEdit.